# CORS, want to get the JSON from different domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, cross-domain

I have a url something like **localhost:8080/abc/v1/doc** and it returns some json when hit directly from browser address bar with these response headers

```
Response Headers 
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
  Content-Type: application/json 
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
  Server: Jetty(9.1.4.v20140401)
```

Even then when I try to load this url from different domain, it throws an exception of :

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

Also I have one more doubt, the REST API Clients are able to call any of the urls even when the **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource** is not present?

How?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "REST API Clients"?

Comment: What response headers does it return when hit via ajax instead of from address bar? From what different domain do you try?

Comment: Advanced REST Client and POSTMAN plugin for chrome, they internally calls the Ajax requests only in order to call the Rest api, how do they bypass this

I have one UI running in localhost:8080/def/loadjson.jsp and in that UI I have an input box where I am placing localhost:8080/abc/v1/doc and clicking the get json and there I am getting the error

Comment: Also the response headers are same when called from browser address or via Postman/Advanced REST Client

Comment: These other clients probably don't care any bit about CORS.

Comment: How they bypass is not my concern my concern is that how can I load localhost:8080/abc/v1/doc in my localhost:8080/def/loadjson.jsp

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for localhost. Problem solved by changing the plugin to the 'RESTClient' (for Firefox webbrowser https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/restclient/).